# How can I read the value out of a tagged pdf?

Tags: c#, pdf, syncfusion

My PDF contains a list of persons and I'm currently looking for an ideal solution to get these persons but in some cases, I ended up reading this sentence:

> It is not possible because PDFs don't have a structure.

Now the thing is there are tagged PDFs that shows you the "structure" of your PDF. In my case I have a tagged PDF where each value of the person has it's own row and each person is in a column. This means that there is/should be a simple way to parse through this "table" in my PDF to get each person's value, right?

So my question is: When tagged PDFs have a structure then how can I benefit from it so I can read all the values I need?

(Side small question: Are PDF to Excel applications using the tags from the PDF to create the Excel file?)

**EDIT #1:**

This is an example of the PDF file:
[image]

I already tried your suggested way @Lara with SyncFusion but the problem is the string I receive:

```
John Peter Smith Smithstrasse 1 0101 Smithikon am See 010 010 01 01 020 020 02 02
```

It is impossible to use Regex with such an output. The problem is you never know if `Peter` in this case belongs to first or last name and `Smith` could be a part of the street. That's why I can't use it and that's the reason why I'm searching for a solution where I can use the tags in the PDF. Everything is nice separated so I only need a way to get the values from the tags.
[image]

**EDIT #2:**
As @Balasubramanian wished for here's a tagged PDF example:
http://www.sh.ch/fileadmin/Redaktoren/Dokumente/Aufsichtsbehoerde_ueber_das_Anwaltswesen/Verzeichnis_SH_Anwaelte.pdf

This PDF gives with syncfusion exactly the output I add in Edit #1.

I don't have any special requirements for the output so it doesn't matter if I receive the data in a JSON file, an array or something similar. What, on the other hand, is important is that each value of each person is separated so I can get this values. But the big question is how I can do that. The tags must be somewhere saved in the PDF file (metadata?).

Answer (score 0):

ITextSharp is an open source .net library you can use in order to read the contents of PDF file. Below code does the same.

```
public static string GetTextFromAllPages(String pdfPath)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath); 

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();  

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) 
        output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

    return output.ToString();
}
```

You can get the library from https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ or Nuget too. Just download and refer in your application and use the above code snippet. You will be able to extract PDF into text.

Update:

Below is what i would suggest you to try ..

```
 string pDFExtract = "John Peter Smith Smithstrasse 1 0101 Smithikon am See 010 010 01 01 020 020 02 02";

 string[] arrpDFExtract = pDFExtract.Split(' ');

 string Name = arrpDFExtract[0] +" "+ arrpDFExtract[1];
```

Here, you have to find out what is the size of the string array and based on that you have to build conditions to which you will get the exact values you want... Analysis of the condition of array length and its corresponding values you have to do..Post which just use above way and get the things out of the PDF.

I have done lots of Document processing using these kind of algorithm building and every thing works just like charm.

Comment: Not the answer I'm looking for. I know this could work but this will, I guess, print line by line but I need the values seperated. Due to the formatation I can't use Regex to get them from the line.

Comment: What kind of formation you have. Above solution extracts the PDF into String.Now you have whole lot of methods available in string to add your logic on and get what you want..

Comment: For you information, read the values line by line in a string..Then split the line based on some delimiter such as " "(Space) and add into string array ..Now find out what information is available at what place of string array. Get that out and use as per your requirement...

Comment: That's the problem. I don't have any delimiter I could use. I edit my quesion

Answer (score 0):

At present **Syncfusion** do not have support for extracting the text from the Tagged PDF document. However can you please provide the **expected output structure** from the tagged PDF document and also the PDF document with which you are trying to extract the texts from it.